# count of records that have matched conditions inside a bool query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have an ES query along the lines of  (condition1 or condition2 or condition3....) and otherConditions.

Each condition inside the brackets is  a 'must' clause that searches for all documents that match a given name, location and product.

```
GET index/type/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "NAME": {
                    "value": "name1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PRODUCT": {
                    "value": "product1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "LOCATION": {
                    "value": "location1"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "NAME": {
                    "value": "name2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PRODUCT": {
                    "value": "product2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "LOCATION": {
                    "value": "location2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "some other condition"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "somefield": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "now-6M"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get count of  records that matches each of the 'must' clause inside the 'should' clause instead of an overall count using one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using aggregations, in particular [`filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) aggregation. The query might look like this:

```
POST index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        "<clause1>",
        "<clause2>"
      ],
      "must_not": [
        "<mustNotClause3>"
      ],
      "must": [
        "<mustClause4>"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "clause1": {
      "filter": "<clause1>"
    },
    "clause2": {
      "filter": "<clause2>"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we are using `_search` API here. If you don't need search results, you can set `size: 0`, this will return you only total count and the aggregations.

In your case the query will literally be this:

```
POST index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "NAME": {
                    "value": "name1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PRODUCT": {
                    "value": "product1"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "LOCATION": {
                    "value": "location1"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "NAME": {
                    "value": "name2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "PRODUCT": {
                    "value": "product2"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "LOCATION": {
                    "value": "location2"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "some other condition"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "somefield": "value"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "now-6M"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "clause1": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "NAME": {
                  "value": "name1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "PRODUCT": {
                  "value": "product1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "LOCATION": {
                  "value": "location1"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "clause2": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "NAME": {
                  "value": "name2"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "PRODUCT": {
                  "value": "product2"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "LOCATION": {
                  "value": "location2"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that sum of counts of aggregations `clause1` and `clause2` may be greater than total count.

Hope that helps!